# is it ok to use Phantom mics w/o phantom power

Tags: phantom

I have some desktop mics, (Shure Microflex412), which are phantom powered. 
What if i plug it in into powered mixer, without any phantom power ?

I used these mics on Peavy powered mixer, which does not have any phantom power support. They seem to work fine. 
By using them such way am i destroying the mics ?

Do i really have to use Phantom power to use it ?

thanks
jack

Comment: An also please do tell me , 
what if i plug in a regular mic into phantom power port. 
What will happen to regular SM58 mic if it gets phantom power ???

Comment: They won't work without power. They don't create power like a dynamic mic. What model is the Peavey mixer?

Comment: they seem to work fine without phantom.
peavy is a powered mixer.
http://peavey.com/products/index.cfm/item/700/116558/PVi%26nbsp%3B8B

Comment: I had a look at the mic specs *before* I wrote that message, theres no batt,, and it says ***"Phantom power required?  11 to 52 Vdc phantom, 2.0 mA "***. As far as *I* can tell, it shouldn't work. It needs a current to produce an output. There are members here that know more than me about mics though. Is there another mixer/device you could try the mic with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **A quote from page 6 of the [PDF Manual](http://assets.peavey.com/literature/manuals/116558_26336.pdf) for the [Peavey PVi® 8B](http://peavey.com/products/index.cfm/item/700/116558/PVi%26nbsp%3B8B):**

> (1) 3-PIN LOW-IMPEDANCE MICROPHONE INPUT This input is for typical
>   balanced, low-impedance microphones. It will automatically provide
>   phantom power (15V) for condenser mics or active direct boxes. This
>   has an input impedance of 1k ohms. The connector is wired as: Pin
>   1=shield; Pin 2=positive (hot); Pin 3=negative (cold).

So the mixer *does* provide Phantom Power automatically.

I also found this at the end of a search string beginning with the [PDF](http://assets.peavey.com/literature/manuals/116558_26336.pdf) and ending with [**Wikipedia - Microphone preamplifier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone_preamplifier)

### **(from Wikipedia - Reffering to [Microphone preamplifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone_preamplifier))**

> Functions
>
> In addition to providing gain for the microphone signal, a microphone
>   preamplifier as found in a sound mixer or as a discrete component
>   typically also provides power to the microphone in the form of Phantom
>   power.

So it looks like it's a typical function for powered mixers.

Answer (score 3):

If those mics works without phantom check if they have a battery installed as they can work with battery power to provide the phantom. Condenser mics will not work without phantom. If you plug a dynamic mic like sm58 nothing bad will happen. You should be cautious when you use more sensitive mics like the most of the ribbon mics that will be damaged by the phantom voltage.

Comment: can you guys please check if the mic is really phantom power one ?
its SHURE microflex A412B.
http://www.shure.com/americas/products/microphones/microflex/mx412-mx418-gooseneck-microphones#details

Comment: Yes, i checked it before answering. It seems peavey has phantom power.